# HTML5 Canvas Mouse Wheel Event

Tags: firefox, html, canvas

I can't seem to get onMouseWheel events in an HTML5 canvas in Firefox.  The following snippet works as expected in Chrome and IE9, but in Firefox I only receive the click event:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="TestCanvas" tabindex="2" onmousewheel="window.alert('wheel!')" onclick="window.alert('click!')" style="width:90%;height:90%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto border:1px solid green;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

According to the specifications I've seen, onMouseWheel should be a standard event on HTML5 elements.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firefox [does not support](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html) the `mousewheel` event. (I just tested in Firefox 4 and seems like it *still* doesn't support it.)

You can use the `DOMMouseScroll` event instead, though you can't attach through the DOM attribute. You have to use addEventListener instead.

Here is [a jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YD7kH/1/) using jQuery to do it.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, that works in FF 4.  Is that a Firefox-only event?